# CRM 2011 + Custom Workflow to fetch user with Specifed role

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, workflow-activity

Hi i am totally new to crm2011.
i need to write a custom workflow.

To do the following things -

```
 1)I want to pass Role Name as "Manager" or something
 2)and on the basis of Role Name a user should be returned who is assigned that role.
```

From what i have understood is i need to join the below 3 tables -

```
System user
System user roles
Roleset
```

After searching a lot on how to create a workflow i have landed with this -

```
class GetUserRole:CodeActivity
{
     [Output("Current User")]
     [ReferenceTarget("systemuser")]
     public OutArgument<EntityReference> CurrentUser { get; set; }
     string securityrole ="Manager";

     protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext Execution)
     {

       IWorkflowContext context = Execution.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
       IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                        Execution.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();

       IOrganizationServiceservice=
             serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

       var entity = organizationService.Retrieve("systemuser",context.PrimaryEntityId,new ColumnSet(new String [] {"systemuserid", "firstname", "lastname"}));

      //Here i need to add the logic to fetch the user from the system with the mentioned role

     //set Current user to the returned value (User)
     }
```

What i need is similar to below fetchxml query but i am not understanding how should i use it in my code since i am not very familiar with the custom workflow syntax

```
 <fetch mapping="logical" count="50" version="1.0">
 <entity name="systemuser">
 <attribute name="fullname" />
 <link-entity name="systemuserroles" from="systemuserid" to="systemuserid">
  <link-entity name="role" from="roleid" to="roleid">
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="name" operator="eq" value="salesperson" />
    </filter>
  </link-entity>
</link-entity>
```

Or i found this code also but could not make it useful in my case

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("systemuser");

query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "systemuserid" });
query.Distinct = true;
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.AddCondition("businessunitid", ConditionOperator.Equal,  ((EntityReference)entity.Attributes["new_unit"]).Id);
query.AddLink("systemuserroles", "systemuserid", "systemuserid").
AddLink("role","roleid", "roleid").
    LinkCriteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "MyRoleName");

var users = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Please if anybody could guide me with this. i am totally lost.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do the search, if you don't care about Business Unit (i.e., you only are using one Business Unit.) You'll need to change the `return` statement to set the Output parameter `CodeActivity.Execute` is a `void` method.

```
string roleName = "System Administrator";

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("systemuser");

query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "systemuserid" });
query.Distinct = true;
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.AddLink("systemuserroles", "systemuserid", "systemuserid").
AddLink("role","roleid", "roleid").LinkCriteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, roleName);

var users = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);

if (users.Entities.Count() > 0) return ((Entity)users[0]).ToEntityReference();
```